# How can I access DOM Elements declared within a template outside Template.myTemplate.events, Template.myTemplate.rendered etc

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template with few elements (input, radioButton etc). If I want to access to these DOM elements within mytemplate I can either access them within events

```
Template.myForm.events({
  'click #submitButton' : function (event, template) {
       //template variable here gives me access to the 
       //current template instance, so I can get to any 
       //DOM element within this template.
   }
})
```

OR within

```
Template.myForm.rendered = function () {
  //within this function I have access to "this" which points to template instance
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to access the DOM Elements that a declared within a template outside of these event functions and rendered callback?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to the rendered callback, the template instance is also available as `this` in the created (DOM won't be available) and destroyed callbacks. In helpers, you can use `Template.instance()`, but the DOM won't be available the first time the helpers are called. This should generally be all of the places you would need to access the template's DOM. Otherwise, there is probably an easier way to solve whatever you're trying to do. Remember, meteor favors storing data with JavaScript structures, rather than storing it in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the insight...Storing data in Javascript structures rather than the DOM

Answer (score 2):

You can but you need to reference the template instance.

The reason for this is a single template can be used multiple times. In this case a single easy to use way to access the template would not know which instance it would belong to. This is why you need to use a reference, such as done in the example below.

You have to store the instance somewhere when it is rendered:

```
TheTemplateInstance = null;

Template.myForm.rendered = function() {
    TheTemplateInstance = this;
}
```

Then you can use `TheTemplateInstance` anywhere you want, provided the template is on the DOM.

If you use `myForm` many times then it will only have access to the one created last.

Also You did not give a use case for your intentions. But there are several better ways to do most things with a template:

JQuery modding something when some variable changes (the most common use case where helpers aren't useful)

```
Template.myForm.rendered = function() {

    var self = this;

    this.autorun(function() {
        var xx = something.findOne();

        self.$("something").autoform() //Some jquery call            
    });

}
```

and helpers:

```
Template.myForm.helpers({
   someName: function() {
       return Session.get("name");
   }
});
```

You can then use `{{someName}}` in your template's html where it can change when you use `Session.set("name", "a new value");`